# Multiple select Queries with group by and sum()

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am having 4 tables(A,B,C,D) with columns date and amount(No id)

I need the resultant table like bellow. group by date from each table sum(amount). I tried my self with lot of select and join queries but didn't get exact result.
help me

Table A

```
date              amount
____________________________
03/07/2015        100
03/07/2015        200
04/07/2015        300
```

Table B

```
date              amont
____________________________
04/07/2015        300
```

Table C

```
date
____________________________
05/07/2015        400
```

Table D

```
date
____________________________
06/07/2015        500
06/07/2015        300
```

Resultant Table

```
date            Sum(A)      Sum(B)     Sum(C)    Sum(D)   Total
_______________________________________________________________
03/07/2015      300          -           -         -       300
04/07/2015      300          300         -         -       600
05/07/2015      -            -          400        -       400
06/07/2015      -            -           -         800     800  
_______________________________________________________________
ToTal:          600          300        400        800     2100
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first `UNION ALL` the rows of each table and add an additional column, `tbl` to determine where the records came from.

```
WITH CteUnion([date], amount, tbl) AS(
    SELECT [date], amount, 'A' FROM A UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'B' FROM B UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'C' FROM C UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'D' FROM D
)
SELECT
    [date],
    A = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'A' THEN amount END),
    B = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'B' THEN amount END),
    C = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'C' THEN amount END),
    D = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'D' THEN amount END),
    Total = SUM(amount)
FROM CteUnion
GROUP BY [date]
```

Using subquery, instead of a `CTE`:

```
SELECT
    [date],
    A = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'A' THEN amount END),
    B = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'B' THEN amount END),
    C = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'C' THEN amount END),
    D = SUM(CASE WHEN tbl = 'D' THEN amount END),
    Total = SUM(amount)
FROM (
    SELECT [date], amount, 'A' AS tbl FROM A UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'B' FROM B UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'C' FROM C UNION ALL
    SELECT [date], amount, 'D' FROM D
)t
GROUP BY [date]
```

Comment: Sir I am getting this : Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
No column name was specified for column 3 of 't'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'tbl'.

Comment: Should be fine now @Vikram

Comment: @Vikram, sqluser's edit should fix your error. What query are you using? the `CTE`or the subquery?

Comment: What's the error? Have you tried re-running the query using @sqluser's edit?